# How do I programmatically start/stop an EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jmx

Does anyone know if it's possible to start/stop an EJB within my application code? Eg. I have some MDBs that I wish to selectively start/stop while my application is running? Any ideas? Can this maybe be done via JMX?

Cheers!

Comment: What is the version of JBoss?

Comment: Hi. Version is 4.2.1.GA.

Answer (score 1):

The EJB spec has no mechanism to start/stop individual EJBs (or even modules) within an application.  It is possible to start/stop applications dynamically using JMX via [JSR 77](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=77).

(I see you're using the jboss tag.  I have no expertise in JBoss, so I don't know if it provides extensions that support what you want to do.)

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather stay within the spec anyway so it looks like it's not going to be a goer.

Answer (score 1):

An EJB is not something that can be "started" or "stopped". Sure, it has a [life cycle](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/EJBConcepts9.html) but that is more concerned with creation, activation, passivation and removal of EJB *instances*, and it's entirely up to the EJB container to manage the life cycle.

In short: you can't manage an EJB's life cycle programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Each deployed MDB has a management MBean. The MBean class is **org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MdbDelegateWrapper**. The JMX ObjectName varies between versions of JBoss 4, and vary depending on how you deployed them. Assuming you deployed an MDB called *MyMDB* in a jar called *myapp.jar*  which was in an ear called *myapp.ear*, the name might be:

```
jboss.j2ee:ear=myapp.ear,jar=myapp.jar,name=MyMDB,service=EJB3
```

Older version of JBoss 4 also had a system hashcode in there. And if you're not using EJB3, I *think* the service will still be there only it will be *EJB2*.

Anyways, once you find the management bean, you can call the **stop** and **start** operations. We use this frequently to pause message delivery.