# Need help to handle MDB Exception in two ways

Tags: jms, jboss-mdb

I'm trying to handle two different types of problems while processing a message.

The first problem is if the remote database is down.  In that case, the message should stop processing, and try again later.  This message should never go to a DLQ, and should keep trying until the remote database is up.

The second problem is when there is a problem with the message.  In that case, it should go to the DLQ.

How should I be structuring the following code?

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {

    // Do some processing
    messageProcessing(message);  // Should DLQ if message is bad

    // Save to the database
    putNamedLocation(message);  // <<--- Exception when external DB is down

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        mdc.setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can detect bad messages definitively in the code body of the MDB, I would write the bad messages to the DLQ directly. This gives you a bit more freedom to perhaps categorize the error and optionally send different types of bad messages to different "DLQ-Like" queues, and/or apply a time-to-live to DLQ'ed messages so that no-hope-of-ever-being-processed type messages don't pile up in the queue for ever. You can add @Resource annotated instance variables to your MDB class referencing the ConnectionFactory and Queue references to support the sending of the messages to the target DLQ. The bottom line is, make sure you detect the error and DLQ the message yourself.

As for the DB being down, you can detect this by catching exceptions when acquiring a connection or writing your updates. In this case, clean up your resources and throw a RuntimeException. This will cause the message to be redelivered, but you will want to check the JMS configuration for two things:

1. Make sure the max-redelivery count is high enough, otherwise the count will tick over and the message will be DLQed eventually anyway.
2. If your JMS implementation supports it, add a redelivery delay to rejected messages to allow some time for the DB to come back up, otherwise your messages will endlessly spin in a deliver/reject loop.

To avoid #2  (which is tricky if your JMS implementation does not support redilvery delay, like WebSphereMQ), you can use the JBoss JMX management interface for the MDB to stop (and later restart) delivery on the MDB. However, you can't do this inside the MDB in the same thread that is processing the message because the MDB will wait for the message to complete processing, which it can't because it is waiting for the MDB to stop, which it can't because...[and so on]  so... your best bet is to start some sort of sentry that polls the DB and when it finds it down, stops the MDB and when it finds it up again, restarts it. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580951/how-do-i-programmatically-start-stop-an-ejb) for a snippet on how to do that.

That last part should help deal with any unexpected exceptions resulting from message validations. (i.e. the DB is fine, but for some reason the message is totally fubar resulting in uncaught exceptions which causes the message to be redelivered). Since down-DB messages should not be redelivered more than a few times (on account of your sentry), you can check a message's redelivery count and if it is ridiculously high then you know you have poison message and you can ditch it, or DLQ it.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: That's helpful.  I was hoping there would be a better way other than directly pushing the message to the DLQ, but your answer does give me some options!